# How to find a sequence of letter in a given string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, c++14, c++17

My string is `"AAABBAABABB"`,
and I want to get the result as

```
A = 3
B = 2
A = 2
B = 1 
A = 1
B = 2
```

I have tried to use

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    if (msg[i] == msg[i + 1]) {
        if(msg[i]==A)
            a++;
        else
            b++;
    }
}
```

I tried this by it didn't work for me. And I don't understand if there any other ways to find it out. Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate through the array by followings:

1. If i = 0, we can set a variable as 0th character  and counter by 1.
2. If ith character is  equal to the previous character, we can increase the counter.
3. If ith character is not equal to the (i-1)th character we can print the character, counter and start counting the new character.

Try the following snippet:

```
char ch = msg[0];
int cnt = 1;

for (int i = 1; i < n; i ++){
   if(msg[i] != msg[i-1]){
      cout<<ch<<" "<<cnt<<endl;
      cnt = 1;
      ch = msg[i];
   }
   else {
      cnt++;
   }
}

cout<<ch<<" "<<cnt<<endl;
```

Comment: Usually, when you access an item of an array, you'd make sure it actually has the item.  `char ch = msg[0];` is out-of-bounds if msg is actually empty.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::vector<std::pair<char, std::size_t>>` to store character occurrences.

Eventually, you would have something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<char, std::size_t>> occurrences;
    std::string str{ "AAABBAABABB" };

    for (auto const c : str) {
        if (!occurrences.empty() && occurrences.back().first == c) {
            occurrences.back().second++;
        } else {
            occurrences.emplace_back(c, 1);
        }
    }

    for (auto const& it : occurrences) {
        std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It will output:

```
A 3
B 2
A 2
B 1
A 1
B 2
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:21,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:21),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++std::vector%3Cstd::pair%3Cchar,+std::size_t%3E%3E+occurrences%3B%0A++++std::string+str%7B+%22AAABBAABABB%22+%7D%3B%0A%0A++++for+(auto+const+c+:+str)+%7B%0A++++++++if+(!!occurrences.empty()+%26%26+occurrences.back().first+%3D%3D+c)+%7B%0A++++++++++++occurrences.back().second%2B%2B%3B%0A++++++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++++++occurrences.emplace_back(c,+1)%3B%0A++++++++%7D%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++for+(auto+const%26+it+:+occurrences)+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+it.first+%3C%3C+%22+%22+%3C%3C+it.second+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:'1',compilationPanelShown:'0',compiler:clang_trunk,compilerOutShown:'0',execArgs:'',execStdin:'',fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B11',source:1,stdinPanelShown:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+Executor+(Editor+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Answer (score 3):

This is very similar to run length encoding. I think the simplest way (less line of codes) I can think of is like this:

```
void runLength(const char* msg) {
    const char *p = msg;
    while (p && *p) {
        const char *start = p++;  // start of a run
        while (*p == *start) p++;  // move p to next run (different run)
        std::cout << *start << " = " << (p - start) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Please note that:

1. This function does not need to know the length of input string before hand, it will stop at the end of string, the '\0'.
2. It also works for empty string and NULL. Both these work: `runLength("");` `runLength(nullptr);` 
   I can not comment yet, if you look carefully, mahbubcseju's code does not work for empty msg.

Comment: This is the simplest way!

Answer (score 1):

With std, you might do:

```
void print_sequence(const std::string& s)
{
    auto it = s.begin();    
    while (it != s.end()) {
        auto next = std::adjacent_find(it, s.end(), std::not_equal_to<>{});
        next = next == s.end() ? s.end() : next + 1;

        std::cout << *it << " = " << std::distance(it, next) << std::endl;
        it = next;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b319604eb17751c9)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Oooh, an algorithm problem? I'll add a recursive example:

```
#include <iostream>

void countingThing( const std::string &input, size_t index = 1, size_t count = 1 ) {
   if( input.size() == 0 ) return;

   if( input[index] != input[index - 1] ) {
      std::cout << input[index - 1] << " = " << count << std::endl;
      count = 0;
   }

   if( index < input.size() ) return countingThing( input, index + 1, count + 1 );
}

int main() {
   countingThing( "AAABBAABABB" );
   return 0;
}
```

To help work out algorithms and figuring out what to write in your code, I suggest a few steps:

First, write out your problem in multiple ways, what sort of input it expects and how you would like the output to be.

Secondly, try and solve it on paper, how the logic would work - a good tip to this is try to understand how YOU would solve it. Your brain is a good problem solver, and if you can listen to what it does, you can turn it into code (it isn't always the most efficient, though).

Thirdly, work it out on paper, see if your solution does what you expect it to do by following your steps by hand. Then you can translate the solution to code, knowing exactly what you need to write.